# Function response type based on input string

Tags: typescript

I'm trying to write a client for the bitcoin json-rpc api and want strong type guarantees. However I can't seem to find an easy why to define the response type of the `call` function based on the input of the cmd parameter.

The code I have below works (you can change the last line to `call("getnewaddress").amount` and it will error, but it seems to verbose. Is there an more programmatic way to do this?

```js
interface RPCResponse {
  getbalance: {
      amount: number
  };
  getnewaddress: {
      address: string
  };
}

type RPCCommand = keyof RPCResponse;

type RPCResponses<T> = 
    T extends "getbalance" ? RPCResponse["getbalance"] :
    T extends "getnewaddress" ? RPCResponse["getnewaddress"] :
    never;

function call<T extends RPCCommand>(cmd: T): RPCResponses<T> {
    
    if (cmd === "getbalance")
        return { amount: 1 } as RPCResponses<T>;

    if (cmd === "getnewaddress")
        return {address: "test"} as RPCResponses<T>;

  throw new Error("never");
}

console.log(call("getnewaddress").address)
```

Answer (score 0):

In TypeScript, you can have multiple signatures on a function by using [Function Overloading](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/functions.html#overloads).

This code is relatively simple while providing strong type guarantees.

```
interface RPCResponseBalance {
    amount: number;
}

interface RPCResponseAddress {
    address: string;
}


function call(cmd: 'getbalance'): RPCResponseBalance;
function call(cmd: 'getnewaddress'): RPCResponseAddress;
function call(cmd: unknown) {
    if (cmd === "getbalance")
        return { amount: 1 }

    if (cmd === "getnewaddress")
        return { address: "test" }

    throw new Error("never");
}

console.log(call("getnewaddress").address)
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgEoAUDCqIGcAOA9iLhAEJwA2cISyA3gFDIvJwC2hAruAFzIgu7AEbQA3IwC+jRqEixEKDNjxESEAIIATLVDy4GzVnB17cufrjBRQAcwnSZMHgjDBiyBFUoAKBOy1+AHJbCDBhKhokIIBKfmUcAmJSCmpaCAlnWjcPL0pff0DkELCQCAB3E119WPisRLVSbWrzTJcckE9vPwD+HgBrEEJykBjDVmRgGGQerWQAXkXkACJQ8Mj05ZijCZY9MC4oTvo2Th4wfgBGZEcJqZnChaXV0oqqs1wtnd39w+O2Uz6fjLSBWZY3GQTMAACygwwEFWQAFEoHCoD5lmUAG7QLYOGQIZKESgQAB0lEItj83ReYDKlUB5i2pPe+hiQA)